# Get the Nth element in a List as a List instead of a number in LISP?

Tags: list, lisp

Let's say you have

```
(setq list '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

when using Nth to return the first element, the result is a number:

```
(nth 0 list)
Result: 1
```

Is there a way to get the result back as a List or convert result to list? Such as:

```
Result: (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can always turn any object to a [`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_list.htm) using the [`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_list_.htm) function:

```
(defparameter *list* '(1 2 3 4 5))
(list (nth 0 *list*))
==> (1)
```

If, however, you are looking to get the *slice* of the argument that contains the number, you need to realize that it is impossible without **modifying** the argument `*list*`:

```
(defparameter *tail* (nthcdr 2 *list*))
*tail*
==> (3 4 5)
```

The following truncates **both** `*tail*` **and** `*list*`:

```
(setf (cdr *tail*) nil)
*tail*
==> (3)
*list*
==> (1 2 3)
```